# I have recenlty create one module but view file not call. return 404

Tags: magento2, frontend, view

I have recently learn **magento 2.1.2**. so I have create one basic module. but view file not call. Its **return 404** on frontend side.

[image]

Above is my module directory structures.

routes.xml

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="standard">
        <route id="testimonial" frontName="testimonial">
            <module name="DDTestimonial_Testimonial" />
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

Block.php

```
namespace DDTestimonial\Testimonial\Block;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;


    class Testimonial extends Template{

        public function __construct(Template\Context $context, array $data = array()) {
            parent::__construct($context, $data);
        }

        public function getTestimonial(){
            return "Testimonial work fine";
        }

    }
```

Controller

```
namespace DDTestimonial\Testimonial\Controller\Index;

use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\ForwardFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\NotFoundException;
use Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface;


class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context{
    protected  $resultPageFactory;
    protected  $resultForwardFactory;
    protected $helper;

    public function __construct(Context $context, PageFactory $resultPageFActory,  ForwardFactory $resutlForwardFactory, \DDTestimonial\Testimonial\Helper\Data $helper) {

            $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFActory;
            $this->resultForwardFactory = $resutlForwardFactory;
            $this->helper = $helper;
            parent::__($context);

    }

    public function dispatch(RequestInterface $request){
        if(!$this->helper->isEnabled()){
            throw new NotFoundException(__("Page not found"));
        }
        return parent::dispatch($request);
    }

    public function execute(){
        $resultPage = $this->resultPageFactory->create();
        $resultPage->getConfig()->getTitle->set(__("Testimonial Page"));
        if(!$resultPage){
            $resultForward = $this->resultForwardFactory->create();
            return $resultForward->forward("not route");
        }
        return $resultPage;
    }


}
```

Layout

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <title>Testimonial Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="DDTestimonial\Testimonial\Block\Testimonial" name="testimonialPage" template="DDTestimonial_Testimonial::testimonial.phtml" />
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

Comment: Paste ur `routes.xml` & it's going in `Block\Testimonail.php` file using echo exit?

Comment: i have try to exit but no luck. please check updated question

Comment: Have you check your module is enable or not ? have you run setup:upgrade command after creating this module ?

Comment: `protected function _prepareLayout() {
        parent::_prepareLayout();
        echo 12;exit;
        return $this;
}` put this code in ur `Block\Testimonail.php`

Comment: yes its enable i have check in backend as well as setup:upgrade.

Comment: @AnkitShah i have try your code but still return 404

Comment: http://127.0.0.1/m2n/testimonial/index/index or  http://127.0.0.1/m2n/testimonial both try on frontend

Comment: https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-module-development/
https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-module-development/view-block-layout-template-magento-2.html

Comment: @AjayPatel okay post layout file ? post layout file code ?you need to call your block in layout file like - `<block class="DDTestimonial\Testimonial\Block\Testimonial" name="testimonial" template="testimonial.phtml" />`

Comment: Please post your controller.

Comment: @KhoaTruongDinh i have upload controller as well as layout.

Comment: Put `die` in the execute method.

Comment: I have try as mention in your ans. but not work

Comment: Your controller extends wrong class `\Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context`. It should extend from `\Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action`.

Comment: @KhoaTruongDinh i have extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action and got this error  Fatal error: Class 'Magento\Framework\App\Action' not found in

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51854/discussion-between-khoa-truongdinh-and-ajay-patel).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When building a simple custom module, we usually meet 404 not found page when trying to call the new custom url. In this case, we need to check:

- Route: make sure we declare the route in `etc/frontend/routes.xml`.
- Controller: we build the controller. (we can put `die` in the execute method to check our controller can work)
- Block: for showing content. (can build later after checking Controller)

And then, try to check our controller: for example: `http://domain/[frontName]/[actionPath]/[actionName]`

**Note:**
Your controler should extend from `\Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action`.

Answer (score 0):

You have error in your controller file :

Try Replace below code with your controller :

```
    <?php

    namespace DDTestimonial\Testimonial\Controller\Index;

    use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
    use Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory;
    use Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\ForwardFactory;
    use Magento\Framework\Exception\NotFoundException;
    use Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface;


    class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
   {
        protected  $resultPageFactory;
        protected  $resultForwardFactory;
        protected $helper;

        public function __construct(Context $context, PageFactory $resultPageFActory,  ForwardFactory $resutlForwardFactory, \DDTestimonial\Testimonial\Helper\Data $helper) {

                $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFActory;
                $this->resultForwardFactory = $resutlForwardFactory;
                $this->helper = $helper;
                parent::__($context);

        }

        public function dispatch(RequestInterface $request){
            if(!$this->helper->isEnabled()){
                throw new NotFoundException(__("Page not found"));
            }
            return parent::dispatch($request);
        }

        public function execute(){
            $resultPage = $this->resultPageFactory->create();
            $resultPage->getConfig()->getTitle->set(__("Testimonial Page"));
            if(!$resultPage){
                $resultForward = $this->resultForwardFactory->create();
                return $resultForward->forward("not route");
            }
            return $resultPage;
        }


    }
```

> After that remove **var/generation** and **var/cache** folder and run
>   **setup:di:compile** and **cache:clean** command. It will works

Comment: i have got this error : Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action::__()

Comment: @AjayPatel have you replce this controller ? have you tried `Magento/Framework/App/Action/Action` ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to extend class **\Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action**

You extend

**class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context{**

Change above code with

**class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action{**